# Delete properties file is not performing

Tags: java

I am trying to delete a properties file that is uploaded,where normal text file is deleting and properties file not deleting.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\cssproperties\\317cssSelector.properties");
boolean success = file.delete();
```

If there is any answer appreciated

Comment: there is an answer, provided there is a question.

Comment: Please tell us what is happening instead of *not performing*

Comment: Use [`Files.delete(file.toPath())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)). Unlike its archaic counterpart it will tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, there's a good chance the file is locked and can't be removed.  Make sure there are no handles open on that file when the server is running.

Comment: Also, if using Windows, a solution could be to run the program (standalone) or the IDE in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

1.Please close OutputStream if you opened somewhere like

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cssSelector_path+userId+"cssSelector.properties");
fos.close();
```

2.File is not opened properly check it is uploaded correctly
3.There might be some OS Permission